# Using named pipes on a machine that has FIPS enabled - C#

Tags: c#, fips

Are there special rules to send messages via named pipes?

I'm using named pipes on a machine that has [FIPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Information_Processing_Standard) enabled.

Comment: Are you asking because you're running into problems?  If so, what specifically is happening?

Answer (score 1):

FIPS mode does not affect named pipes, so there are no special rules to follow.

FIPS mode refers to [FIPS 140-2](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips140-2/fips1402.pdf), a standard that affects cryptographic operations like encryption, hashing, cryptographic key management, and random number generation.  Intuition tells us that named pipes are just a communication channel, ungoverned by FIPS.

But for concrete evidence, we can look at the [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340152.aspx).  It does not throw any exception related to FIPS.  Compare with a managed crypto API, like [SHA1Managed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1managed.sha1managed.aspx).  As of .net 4.0, its constructor throws `InvalidOperationException` when constructed on a system in FIPS mode because it is not a FIPS-certified implementation of SHA-1.

Comment: Any references or quotes to back this up?  I'm not arguing or disagreeing, just saying it would be nice to have a more complete answer than just "no".